# Pathfinder for a puzzle game

Tags: path-finding, puzzle

I want to develop a game like this one : https://gamesge.com/fr/fill-one-line-puzzle-game/

Starting with an empty grid I have to create a pathfinder to fill the grid with one line.

[image: The empty grid]
[image: The filled grid]

I only heard of A* pathfinder and flood-fill algorithm, but I don't think it can help me.
Do you know algorithms which would help me to create my own algorithm to generate the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backtracking algorithm should be good enough to solve that problem